# Rank-$1$ decomposition of symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

At the moment, I am working with Runge-Kutta methods. We can assume that this is given by a Butcher tableau, where $A$, $b$, $c$ can be extracted from.

Consider the matrix $M$, with $M_{ij} := b_i A_{ij} + A_{ji} b_j - b_i b_j$. For all $j$, we have that $b_j > 0$ and that $c \in [0,1]^s$.

In an exercise class, I need to show that

$$ M = \sum_{l=1}^s \mu_l \mu^T_l, \quad \text{$\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}^s$ for $i = 1, \ldots, s.$}$$

So, what I am looking for is a rank-$1$ decomposition of the given matrix $M$.

I tried looking at case $s=2$, but didn't come to any meaningful conclusion. It looks like this:

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
2b_1 a_{11} - b_1^2 & a_{21} b_2 + b_1 a_{12} - b_1 b_2\\
a_{21} b_2 + b_1 a_{12} - b_1 b_2 & 2b_2 a_{22} - b_2^2 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mu_{11}^2 + \mu_{21}^2 & 2\mu_{12} \mu_{21} \\
2\mu_{12} \mu_{21} & \mu_{12}^2 + \mu_{22}^2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I tried expending and making squares, but it doesn't seem to work, e.g.:

$$ a_{11} = 2b_1 a_{11} - b_1^2 - a_{11}^2 + a_{11}^2 = -(a_{11}- b_1)^2 + a_{11}^2.$$

I also thought about applying an adaptation of Cholesky decomposition, but with no success either.

Any hints? It seems that there I need to have more constraints, because for instance for $2 a_{11} < b_1$ in $a_{11}$, I will not get anything of the form form the RHS. So, are there assumptions that I am not considering?

Comment: Use the eigendecomposition.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks. Was too obvious, wasn't it?

Comment: What is the input data? Where is $c$?

Comment: Not relevant in this subquestion. I mentioned it in order to give a proper context, because I thought some information I am missing is "encoded" in the RK-method (like consistence conditions e.g.). The eigendecomposition works, was an ironic comment that I didn't try out the obvious guess :D solved it, thanks!